# Can't get onClick to work in JS file

Tags: javascript, onclick

After two days of effort and research, I can't seem to figure out how to get onClick to work with an image.

**Here's my html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Stupid F'ing Rock!</title>
 <head>   
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="script.js"></script> 
</head>

    <body>
        <img id="touchRock" src="images/rock_unhappy_original.png">
    <body/>
</html>
```

**And here's the code in my js file:**

```
/*global alert */


window.onload = function () {
    alert("Hello, I am your pet rock!");
};
document.getElementById("touchRock").onclick = function () {
    prompt("What is your name?");
};
```

The only thing that works in the JS file is the alert function. I also have the following errors:

```
5       Missing 'use strict' statement.  alert("Hello, I am your pet rock!");
8   Missing 'use strict' statement.  prompt("What is your name?");
8   'prompt' was used before it was defined.     prompt("What is your name?");
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `onclick` function inside the `onload` function, because you're loading the JS file before the body has been loaded and the ID doesn't exist yet.

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("Hello, I am your pet rock!");
    document.getElementById("touchRock").onclick = function() {
        prompt("What is your name?");
    };
};
```